# Regarding bound for n choose k

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While going through the proof given at slide no.5 at http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~hungngo/classes/2011/Spring-694/lectures/union.pdf, I could not figure out how the bound 
$${n\choose k}\le\left(\frac{ne}k\right)^k $$for $n$ choose $k$ and 
$$\left(1 - \frac1{2^k}\right)^{n-k}<e^{-\frac{n-k}{2^k}}$$
comes? Also, how lower bound for $n$ is calculated? Can somebody help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: The page numbering is inconsistent - I assume you mean page 4 which is paginated as "5/16"?

Comment: Hi, I meant slide no.5 that is there on the slide.

Comment: The first part is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132625/n-choose-k-leq-left-fracen-k-rightk)

Answer (score 0):

For the second part: Note that $\left(1-\frac1N\right)^N\to e^{-1}$ as $N\to\infty$, and in fact this seqeunce is increasing. Therefore $$\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^{n-k}=\left(\left(1-\frac1{2^k}\right)^{2^k}\right)^{\frac{n-k}{2^k}}<e^{-\frac{n-k}{2^k}}$$

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about first part. I looked at sterling approximation for n! and I guess that it uses some fact from there.(see wiki for sterling approx.)