# Inequality involving binomial coefficients and $e$

Tags: combinatorics

I found this inequality in a textbook:

$$\binom{n}{k} < \left(\frac{e\cdot n}{k}\right)^k \, .$$
I wonder how to prove it and why $e$ counts here?

Comment: $e$ is intimately related to factorials.

Comment: See another post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132625/n-choose-k-leq-left-fracen-k-rightk