# Show $\log_2{n \choose k} = k\log_2\frac{n}{k} + log_2e$ when $k = o(n)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was trying to show the following:
$$
\log_2{n \choose k} \leq k\log_2\frac{n}{k} + k\log_2(e)
$$
or
$$
\log_2{n \choose k} = k\log_2\frac{n}{k} + O(k)
$$
when $k = o(n)$

My attempt:
\begin{equation}
\log_2{n \choose k} = \frac{\ln{n \choose k}}{\ln2} = \frac{\ln\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}}{ln2} = 
\frac{\ln n! - \ln(n-k)! - lnk!}{ln2} = \frac{n\ln n - n + O(lgn) - (n-k)\ln(n-k) + (n-k) - O(\ln(n-k)) - k\ln k + k - O(\ln k)}{\ln2} \leq \\
\leq \frac{n\ln n - n + a\ln n - (n-k)\ln(n-k) + (n-k) - b\ln(n-k) - k\ln k + k - c\ln k}{\ln2} = \frac{n\ln n \color{red}{- n} + a\ln n - (n-k)\ln(n-k) \color{red}{+ (n-k)} - b\ln(n-k) - k\ln k \color{red}{+ k} - c\ln k}{\ln2} =
 \frac{n\ln n + a\ln n - (n-k)\ln(n-k) - b\ln(n-k) - k\ln k - c\ln k \color{blue}{\pm k\ln n}}{\ln2} = \\
\frac{\color{green}{(n-k)\ln n} + a\ln n \color{green}{-(n-k)\ln(n-k)} -b\ln(n-k) + k\ln\frac{n}{k}- c\ln k}{ln2} = \\ \frac{(n-k)\ln\frac{n}{n-k} + k\ln\frac{n}{k} +a\ln n - b\ln (n-k) - c\ln k}{\ln2}
\end{equation}
Here I'm stuck, how do I get from here to $\log_2{n \choose k} = k\log_2\frac{n}{k} + O(k)$

Comment: Your inequality is equivalent to $\binom{n}{k} \leq \left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k$ which is a duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132625/inequality-n-choose-k-leq-left-fracen-k-rightk?noredirect=1&lq=1